# href is truncating querystring

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, href

I have following querystring in a variable

```
var redirectTo = "http://localhost/DGS.DGSAPI.UI/ORDERONLINE?addr=10 n main&apt=&zip=44408&customer=N";
```

rendered on **View** like:

```
<a href=@redirectTo>Check Here</a>
```

But when it renders, it truncates after it found a space. It rendered following:

> http://localhost/DGS.DGSAPI.UI/ORDERONLINE?addr=10

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use quotation marks, without it a `space` will make the browser think that a new attribute is starting:

```
<a href="@redirectTo">Check Here</a>
```

Also note that spaces inside querystring parameters are normally encoded as `+` symbols. So even with the added quotes, it could still be that the URL won't work correctly when opened.